# Send Email using vb.net 2008

Tags: vb.net, email, gmail

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sending email in .NET through Gmail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail)

I want to send an email using VB.NET2008 and gmail account.
Can any one help me in it any code?

Comment: a quick google search should suffice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim Msg As New MailMessage

Dim myCredentials As New System.Net.NetworkCredential
myCredentials.UserName = " andreas@absender.de"
myCredentials.Password = "Password"

Msg.IsBodyHtml = False

Dim mySmtpsvr As New SmtpClient()
mySmtpsvr.Host = "smtp.web.de" 
mySmtpsvr.Port = 25

mySmtpsvr.UseDefaultCredentials = False
mySmtpsvr.Credentials = myCredentials

Try
  Msg.From = New MailAddress("andreas@absender.de")
  Msg.To.Add("entchen@empfänger.de")
  Msg.Subject = "Betreff"
  Msg.Body = "Inhalt"
  mySmtpsvr.Send(Msg)
  MsgBox("E-Mail gesendet.", MsgBoxStyle.Information, Title:="Information")
Catch ex As Exception
  MsgBox (Err.Number & ex.Message & ex.StackTrace.ToString) 'Falls ein Fehler auftritt wird eine MsgBox angezeigt
End Try
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: thanks for the answer. what host will i use if i choose gmail?

Comment: PostincomeServer: POP3: pop.googlemail.com (SSL; Port 995)

IMAP: imap.googlemail.com (SSL; Port 993)

PostOutComeServer: smtp.googlemail.com (SSL; Port 465 oder 587)

Comment: i finally solve it. thanks a lot!!